# Form-Horizontal not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm new to bootstrap.I'm using it with ReactJS. I'm trying to create a simple horizontal form, which seems to be pretty elusive for me. Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong. Has it got anything to do with the textarea length or something? Is that why it is overflowing to the next line?
I want to make something like this. 
 [Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEiZf.jpg)

```
   <div className="container">
       <div className="row">   
          <div className="col-sm-12 dijitContentPane">                     
             <form id="shopcartAddressForm" className="js-validateForm form- 
   horizontal" width="100%" data-fv-framework="bootstrap">
                     <div className="col-sm-6 ">
                       <div className="form-horizontal">
                         <div className="control-group" >
                            <label for="firstName" className="col-sm-4 control- 
   label no-bold">First Name<span className="red">*</span></label>{/* Takes 4 
   columns of this half column of the container */}     
                            <div className="col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
                              <input tabindex="0" type="text" id="firstName" 
    className="form-control" aria-label="First Name" placeholder="First Name" 
    value=""/>
                            </div>
                            <label for="middleName" className="col-xs-12 col-sm- 
   1 control-label no-bold">MI</label>{/* Takes 1 column as the label */}
                             <div className="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
                             <input tabindex="0" type="text" id="middleName" 
    className="form-control" aria-label="MI" placeholder="MI" value=""/>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>                       
    </div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `className`. Also, your col-*-* are off.

Comment: @hungrykoala This is JSX

Comment: @hungrykoala. I'm using it with ReactJS. Hence the className. Also, could you elaborate regarding the col thing. I'm not sure i quite follow it. Pardon me for asking if it's trivial.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. read this for the grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I would suggest checking the sample form from bootstrap and work your way from there in adding new elements. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am not sure if you referred to bootstrap website because forms can be created easily.

Something like this:

                           <form className="col-md-5">
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                  <label for="staticEmail" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                  <div className="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" readonly className="form-control" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com" />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group row">
                                  <label for="inputPassword" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                                  <div className="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </form>
```

you can refer -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Shoumorup: awesome :).. You can upvote if it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Use Form.Row and Col like below

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col}>
        <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="email" name="email" isInvalid={!isEmpty(errors.email)} value={values.email} onChange={handleChange}></Form.Control>
        <Form.Control.Feedback className="font-weight-bold" type="invalid" role="alert"> {errors.email}</Form.Control.Feedback>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group as={Col}>
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" name="password" value={values.password} isInvalid={!isEmpty(errors.password)} onChange={handleChange}></Form.Control>
        <Form.Control.Feedback className="font-weight-bold" type="invalid" role="alert"> {errors.password}</Form.Control.Feedback>

    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group as={Col} className="text-center">
        <Button type="button" variant="primary" className="mt-3" onClick={submitForm}>Login</Button>
    </Form.Group>
</Form.Row>
</Form>
```

[image]